# how to get current sequence after reorder columns in kendo-vuejs

Tags: vue.js, telerik-grid, columnsorting

When you reorder **columns** then table columns reorder but columns array showing old sequence, so here you didn't get udpated columns list siquence, but in answer section you can get the updated columns list.

```js
columnReorder: function(options) {
 let afterReorderColumns = options.columns; // that is showing old sequence
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```
columnReorder: function(options) {
 let afterReorderColumns = options.target._columns; // current table sequence
},
```